# How do I tie in two tables with SQL join statements?

Tags: sql, dataset

I have 2 tables. Lets call them T1 and T2.

T1 has several columns that I need and is where the main bulk of the information is going to be pulled from.

T2 has only a few columns that I need and is supplemental data. However there are 3 columns that match T1 but will have different data.

Example:

[image: Table_1]

[image: Table_2]

What I am trying to do is create a dataset that will allow me to create a report with Unit# = Unit#, Date = Date, and Employee = Employee. I need 6 columns to become 3 with stacked with its counter part and the rest of the data (ie Picked up, Type, 1, 2, Exception Code) each in columns of their own but still part of the table.

[image: Target Output]

Can someone please help me? I have tried different types of JOINs but I guess I'm connecting them just right.

Comment: It would help if you added an example of the desired output for the sample source data. Since there are matching values for `Unit#` and `Date` it's not clear whatthe result should look like.

Comment: Edited to show Target Output.

Answer (score 1):

If i correctly understood, you need to use the UNION ALL.
Could you please try this script?

```
create table #T1 (Unit varchar(2),[Date] int, Employee int, PickedUp int, TypeField varchar(2),One varchar(5),Two varchar(5))
create table #T2 (Unit varchar(2),[Date] int, Employee int, ExeptionCode varchar(2))


insert into #T1 values ('A',1,20,1,'Z','Misc','Misc')
insert into #T1 values ('B',2,20,2,'Z','Misc','Misc')
insert into #T1 values ('C',3,25,3,'Y','Misc','Misc')
insert into #T1 values ('D',4,30,4,'X','Misc','Misc')
insert into #T1 values ('E',5,31,5,'Y','Misc','Misc')

insert into #T2 values ('F',6,25,'T')
insert into #T2 values ('G',7,20,'T')
insert into #T2 values ('H',8,30,'E')
insert into #T2 values ('I',9,20,'U')
insert into #T2 values ('J',10,20,'U')


select 
Unit, [Date], Employee, PickedUp, TypeField, One, Two, NULL
from 
#T1

UNION ALL

select 
Unit, [Date], Employee, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ExeptionCode
from 
#T2
```

Output is the following:
[image]

Comment: The Tables have already been created in the SQL Server. I'm trying to pull the columns into a dataset then code them into a Report. The data will be queried each day from the columns that are embedded into the dataset. UNION won't work because the Tables have different quantities of columns. JOIN is what I need from what I can understand but I'm missing something to make it work properly.

Comment: In order to have the same number of columns you can insert an empty string where it doesn't exist. You can also add Column1, Column2, Column3 ecc in order to mapping the metadata in the report and use them in future when you will need.